# API urll not working from file_get_contents or curl()

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am using WP json api to get dat a from my wordpress site.It is working fine when i access the url from browser.
but when i try to call it from file_get_contents() or using curl,it returns 404 page .

```
 $url = 'http://example.com/api/menus/get_menu/?menu_location=mainmenu'; // this url works from browser
 $data = file_get_contents($url);
 echo $data; // returns 404 page html
```

Comment: And when you do a `print_r($data);` what do you get? If I'm not mistaken it should return a `json` object, no? In that case you just need to decode it, and work with it.

Comment: it return 404 html,from wordpress

Comment: Have you tried doing like described [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/115902/58895)?

Answer (score 0):

in my case, if i want to call the server 
u need using localhost, or ip local
like 10.200.x.x

or u may lack add space in url parameter

Comment: Please do not answer with a comment/question. Understandably, your rep is too low to comment, but that still does not mean answers should be used to make comments as an alternative. It would be preferable if you deleted this.

Comment: because he got the same  return 404 html, it may got same case with me,. i think my comment got a value added